Angular Service Worker: 404 Error on Specific Pages, 504 Offline (localhost Works Fine)
I'm facing issues with my Angular application's service worker when deployed. Here's a breakdown of the problems:

404 Error on Specific Pages:

When I try to load certain pages, like "/jobs" or similar, I get a 404 Forbidden error in the browser console.
Strangely, the response still contains the actual HTML content, even though it's a 404.
2. 504 Gateway Timeout Offline:
When I attempt to load the application while offline, I receive a 504 Gateway Timeout error (originating from the service worker).
Localhost Works:
It's important to note that everything functions as expected when running the application on my local development server (localhost).
Question:
I'm at a loss at to why these errors are occurring. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated. Here are some specific points I'd like help with:
What could be causing the 404 error on specific pages, even though the response contains the HTML content?
How can I ensure that the service worker doesn't trigger a 504 error when the application is offline (assuming the necessary resources are cached)?
here are the screenshots
when offline
when online
tried different cache configs, tried to cache that specific urls /jobs, /auth, /messages,
tried that on localhost prod build and everything works well.

I don't think your Angular worker service is properly configured and deployed to Azure App. Could you check if there is any errors in your deployment?

After thorough investigation, I've identified and resolved the issue causing the 504 Gateway Timeout error when attempting to load the application offline.
The root of the problem was a discrepancy in the caching mechanism, particularly with the env.json file. This file, crucial for runtime operations, was being cached as a static file rather than within the appropriate data groups. Consequently, during offline mode, the cached env.json file didn't match the expected state due to hash mismatches. This discrepancy led to the service worker triggering a 504 error.
To resolve this, I adjusted the caching configuration to ensure that the env.json file is properly cached within the appropriate data groups, ensuring its integrity during offline usage. After making this adjustment, the application now functions smoothly both online and offline without encountering the 504 error.

what do you mean by evn.json file? can you please share more detail, I'm facing issue.
